# Swift UIEventKit - creating an event for specific days

Tags: swift, uievent

I am pretty new to swift, so I am just hoping someone could help me out - I am trying to use UIEventKit to add an event to the calendar (which I have figured out how to do) however there are two things that I am unsure about:

1 - I want to be able to add the event to the next instance of a particular day. eg. the next coming Monday

2 - I want to be able to have that event recurring on that day a certain number of times - lets say 4.

Any help anyone can offer on either of the above would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what i have so far:

```
func createEvent(eventStore: EKEventStore, title: String, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate){
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)

    event.title = title
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
    do {
        try eventStore.saveEvent(event, span: .ThisEvent)
    }catch {
        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Access Denied", message: "Please change your settings to allow us to access your calendar", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


@IBAction func addToCalendar(sender: UIButton) {

    let eventStore = EKEventStore()
    let startDate = NSDate()
    let endDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60 * 30)

    if (EKEventStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Event) != EKAuthorizationStatus.Authorized) {
        eventStore.requestAccessToEntityType(.Event, completion: {
            granted, error in
            self.createEvent(eventStore, title: "Psychology Lecture", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)

        })

    }else {
        createEvent(eventStore, title: "Psychology Lecture", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to add the event to the next instance of a particular day. eg. the next coming Monday

How are you handling the UI for the app? A best option for this kind of case would be to display the Date Picker - and let the user choose a date. And you can then create an event for that specific date.

> I want to be able to have that event recurring on that day a certain number of times - lets say 4.

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/CreatingRecurringEvents/CreatingRecurringEvents.html) for creating Recurring Events and it seems you cannot have an event recurring n times on a particular day.

I would suggest - creating the event with a different time or creating it an all day event.

For an all day event

```
event.allDay = true
```

For creating the event with a different time - I bumped up the day with different time

```
 createEvent(eventStore, title: "Psychology Lecture", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
 //Bump up the time by 30 minutes
 startDate = startDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60 * 30)
 endDate = endDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(60 * 30)
 self.createEvent(eventStore, title: "Another Psychology Lecture", startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi Karthik, Thanks so much for taking the time to get back to me - unfortunately, it probably would detract from the user experience for them to have to pick their own date to store the event on (as it will be something that just occurs every week). With regards to the recurring events, I dont think I worded that question very well as i actually meant for the event to occur once on the same day for the next 4 weeks, rather than on the same day - i'm not sure whether this is something that is possible?